# convert array into an object angularjs

Tags: angularjs, object, angularjs-scope

I have a contoroller:

```
$scope.getFromDB=function(data)
{
  $scope.nameSelected=[];
  var myCookie=$cookie.get("nameCookie");
   $scope.names= data;
for(var i=0; i<$scope.names.length;i++)
{
   if($scope.names._id=myCookie._id)
     {
       $scope.nameSelected.push($scope.names[i]);
      }
  }
```

I want display the user's firstname, middlename, lastname stored in the `$scope.nameSelected`, since the `nameSelected`is in the array form, name are got in array `nameSelected[0].firstname`, `nameSelected[0].middlename`,`nameSelected[0].lastname`. So how to convert it into a `object` so it is easy to access the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've written,you don't need an array at all, just use an object.
Change this:

```
$scope.nameSelected=[];
...
$scope.nameSelected.push($scope.names[i]);
```

to

```
$scope.nameSelected = null;
...
$scope.nameSelected = $scope.names[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've mentioned in your question, it is already an object at the index `0` of your `nameselected` array, That means, doing,

```
$scope.nameselected[0]
```

should give you this,

```
{firstName : "Robert", middlename :"Downy", lastName:"junior"}
```

Similarly, for all the names as in your loop ,

```
$scope.nameselected = $scope.names[i]
```